# NuGet Crashes VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, crash

NuGet Package Manager crashes my VS2010 Ultimate.  Has anyone experienced this before? I uninstalled the extension and reinstalled.

When I open the package manager the following dialog pops up "Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close."

I'm running NuGet 1.6 and VS2010 version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Thanks in advance

Update:
I did what you suggested. I ended up uninstalling all add-ins and re-installed nuget. Here is the stack trace:

System.AccessViolationException:
{"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

Stack Trace:
   at EnvDTE.ProjectItem.get_Kind()

at NuGet.VisualStudio.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectItem(ProjectItems projectItems, String name, String kind)

at NuGet.VisualStudio.ProjectExtensions.TryGetFile(ProjectItems projectItems, String name, ProjectItem& projectItem)

at NuGet.VisualStudio.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectItem(Project project, String path)

at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsProjectSystem.FileExistsInProject(String path)

at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsProjectSystem.FileExists(String path)

at NuGet.PackageReferenceFile.GetDocument(Boolean createIfNotExists)

at NuGet.PackageReferenceFile.d__0.MoveNext()

at NuGet.PackageReferenceRepository.d__0.MoveNext()

at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)

at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

at NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.d__29.MoveNext()

at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)

at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

at NuGet.Dialog.Providers.UpdatesTreeNode.GetPackages()

at NuGet.Dialog.Providers.PackagesTreeNodeBase.ExecuteAsync(Int32 pageNumber, CancellationToken token)

at NuGet.Dialog.Providers.PackagesTreeNodeBase.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_2(Object state)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InvokeFuture(Object futureAsObj)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()

at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: No, that's quite uncommon.  Usually caused by bad interaction with other extensions, disable some.  Start up another instance of VS and use Tools + Attach to Process to attach to the first one.  So you'll get the diagnostics you'll need to ask a documented question.

Comment: FYI. I copied that issue into NuGet's issue tracker : [#2037](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2037)

Comment: I cannot update from version 1.2.20325 to 2.2.31210... Is it something related to this question maybe?