# NuGet keeps crashing Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am trying to update NuGet dependencies in my Mvc Web Project. I am going to my project, right clicking on it, and going to Manage NuGet Packages. The NuGet package manager pops up and I click on "Updates" and the specific package I'm trying to update is "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages" and "jQuery". If I click on either one of these, and click the update button, the update window pops up, then crashes almost immediately. Visual Studio will then restart and when I open my project, nothing is updated. The error is something about trying to write to protected memory.

Does anyone have any suggestion on what can be causing this? I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 on top of Windows 7.

**Update**

As a follow up to this question, I just wanted to add some more details. I ran Visual Studio with the [/log flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) hoping to get some more information. Here is a dump of some of the last entries in the file:

```
<entry>
  <record>749</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:27.421</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
  <guid>{77A5A151-6A9B-4D08-BC38-340AB29566E2}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>750</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:27.421</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Begin package load [CctSharedPackage]</description>
  <guid>{77A5A151-6A9B-4D08-BC38-340AB29566E2}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>751</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:27.514</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [CctSharedPackage]</description>
  <guid>{77A5A151-6A9B-4D08-BC38-340AB29566E2}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>752</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:29.748</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
  <guid>{BC9CA0B3-BB4F-449A-967C-29A8FAE32086}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>753</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:29.748</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Begin package load [Microsoft VSDesigner WCF Package]</description>
  <guid>{BC9CA0B3-BB4F-449A-967C-29A8FAE32086}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>754</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:29.763</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [Microsoft VSDesigner WCF Package]</description>
  <guid>{BC9CA0B3-BB4F-449A-967C-29A8FAE32086}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>755</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:30.653</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>756</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:30.653</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>757</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:30.653</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>758</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:30.653</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>759</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:32.621</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
  <guid>{5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>760</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:32.621</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>Begin package load [NuGetPackage]</description>
  <guid>{5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
  <record>761</record>
  <time>2015/06/10 15:24:32.637</time>
  <type>Information</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>End package load [NuGetPackage]</description>
  <guid>{5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC}</guid>
</entry>
```

Nothing seems unusual or out of place to me. I looked up the guid's presented in the log file:

```
{5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC} - NuGetConsole.Implementation.PowerConsoleToolWindow
{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2} - SSMS DTE 12.0
```

Also I had originally thought this was isolated to one specific project. Apparently even when I go create a new project, the same thing happens when I try to update it.

The last thing I did before all this happened was install Windows updates. I remember one of the updates that came through was Sql Server 2014 Update 1. I use Management Studio 2014, but I can't think of any kind of relationship between NuGet and Management Studio.

So hopefully this information will help me or help someone else to solve this issue! Any ideas guys?

**Update 2**

I am pasting my exception in here, retrieved from event viewer:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at EnvDTE.ProjectItem.get_Kind()
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.ProjectExtensions+<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetChildItems>b__a(EnvDTE.ProjectItem)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at NuGet.ProjectSystemExtensions.DeleteFiles(NuGet.IProjectSystem, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<NuGet.IPackageFile>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<NuGet.IPackage>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<NuGet.FileTransformExtensions,NuGet.IPackageFileTransformer>)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.RemovePackageReferenceFromProject(NuGet.IPackage)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute(NuGet.PackageOperation)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute(NuGet.IPackage, NuGet.IPackageOperationResolver)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference(NuGet.IPackage, Boolean, Boolean)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.UpdatePackageReference(NuGet.IPackage, Boolean, Boolean)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager+<>c__DisplayClass5a.<UpdatePackageReference>b__58()
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.RunProjectAction(NuGet.IProjectManager, System.Action)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.UpdatePackageReference(NuGet.IProjectManager, NuGet.IPackage, Boolean, Boolean)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager+<>c__DisplayClass1a.<UpdatePackages>b__18()
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager+<>c__DisplayClass67.<ExecuteOperationsWithPackage>b__65()
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.RunSolutionAction(System.Action)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.ExecuteOperationsWithPackage(NuGet.IProjectManager, NuGet.IPackage, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<NuGet.PackageOperation>, System.Action, NuGet.ILogger)
   at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageManager.UpdatePackages(NuGet.IProjectManager, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<NuGet.IPackage>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<NuGet.PackageOperation>, Boolean, Boolean, NuGet.ILogger)
   at NuGet.Dialog.Providers.UpdatesProvider.ExecuteCommand(NuGet.IProjectManager, NuGet.Dialog.Providers.PackageItem, NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageManager, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NuGet.PackageOperation>)
   at NuGet.Dialog.Providers.OnlineProvider.ExecuteCommandOnProject(EnvDTE.Project, NuGet.Dialog.Providers.PackageItem, NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageManager, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NuGet.PackageOperation>)
   at NuGet.Dialog.Providers.OnlineProvider.ExecuteCore(NuGet.Dialog.Providers.PackageItem)
   at NuGet.Dialog.Providers.PackagesProviderBase.OnRunWorkerDoWork(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr, System.Object[], System.Object, System.Object[] ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

There is a [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849055/nuget-crashes-vs2010-ultimate) similar to mine, but for Visual Studio 2010. Our stack traces are identical. Unfortunately, the question was never answered.

**Final Update**

I finally fixed this by just going into Visual Studio setup and repairing the installation.

Comment: are you trying it in debug mode?

Comment: @Sushil - Yes. I'm not trying to build it though.

Comment: hmm.. i usually get it when I try to update it while debugging. do u have any other visual studio plugins that might me causing this?

Comment: @Sushil - The only plugin I use is ReSharper. But I've had that installed forever. This is a new project I just created and for some reason, it only appears to happen on this project.

Comment: i thought so. can you see these links and try out their solutions? http://www.seirer.net/blog/2014/5/20/visual-studio-2013-cant-update-nugetexe and http://www.seirer.net/blog/2014/5/20/visual-studio-2013-cant-update-nugetexe

Comment: @Sushil - These aren't working for me. Installing it from Package Manager Console, I did see that the last thing it tried to do was remove the old version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages`. That is when VS 2013 crashed and popped up a window "Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working" and restarted.

Comment: While I see you have repaired things, make sure you're using the latest Nuget tools by going into Tools->Manage extensions and updating.

Answer (score 1):

Repair your VS 2013, then it's recommended to uninstall the Nuget Package Manager, and download and reinstall it.